# What affects a trader/store generating caps?

Tags: fallout-4

I've heard they make more money the more idle settlers you have but haven't seen proof.

Any ideas?

or is there no changing it and it's just a static flow?

Comment: This is purely my experience. I don't have a good way of proving how it scales, but I did not receive any caps until I had a single idle settler for my single shop.

Comment: As far as I know it is based on the happiness of the settlement.

Comment: I'd love to see a comprehensive answer to this question. I had a settlement with 6 stores in it that would generate 350-400 caps every few days, and it seems to have dropped down to 50 caps a week recently (and now I have ~9 stores: 4 lvl 3 clinics and 1 of each other lvl 2 store). I thought it might be the "idle settler" thing, but I have plenty of idle settlers in there, and I also did a few tests (deleted a few clinics, slept for a week, etc.) and there was no change. Not sure what else could have changed - perhaps other settlements not having enough resources? Random bug?

Answer (score 2):

The "more idle settlers equals higher income" thing was going around various places early on in the game release but is not true.

Cap generation is based on the total population at your settlement and whether they're assigned to a task or not is irrelevant (you'll make the same money from a settlement with 15 people all assigned to something as you will from a settlement with 15 people with 5 of them not assigned to anything). This is also as stated on the [Fallout Wikia page for Trading Posts](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Trading_post):

> Assigning settlers to these trading stands will increase settlement happiness and produce a profit of caps based on population size. Caps can be collected from the settlement's inventory by accessing the workbench.

Comment: +1 I'm going to assume this is true until someone can show otherwise.